# How to create an Azure DevOps release pipeline using YAML config?

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I created Azure DevOps build pipeline in the past using YAML files. Similarly, I want to use a YAML file to create stages in my release pipeline. How can I do that?

Comment: use deployment jobs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are referring to the [classic release pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops), than you can't. The classic release pipelines do not support yaml.

However, you can add a release stage to your yaml build pipeline, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) in the documentation:

```yaml
stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: A1
  - job: A2

- stage: Release
  jobs:
  - job: B1
  - job: B2
```

Comment: Adding to this, if you want to create stages for deployment, I would heavily recommend using the specific job type "deployment", as it gives you access to Environments where you can add control rules and approvers.